# Small matrices in ScaLAPACK: How to deal with empty blocks

Tags: fortran, scalapack

I have a large matrix describing a physical system. The last two rows are fundamentally different from the others, and therefore need to be set up separately. Furthermore, it makes no sense to distribute each of these rows over different processes. I want to set up the two lines on the 0th process and then copy them to the global matrix.

What do I have? - A distributed M x N matrix where the upper (M-2) x N block is already filled.

What do I want to do? - Calculate the last 2 x N elements on the 0th process and then copy them with `PDGEMR2D`

What is the problem? - I need to call `PDGEMR2D` on all processes. The to-be-copied matrix (I think it's usually called `a`) therefore needs to be allocated and have a scalapack descriptor on all processes. On the 0th process, the local matrix is 2 x N, on all other processes it is 0 x N.

**How do I deal with the empty submatrices?**
Usually, to get the scalapack descriptors I would call `descinit` with the local number of rows as `LLD`. However this number needs to be >= 1, but on the processes with the empty matrices it is 0.

(Note that fortran lets you allocate arrays with 0 elements - this is purely a ScaLAPACK issue.)

Comment: I need to look into this myself for my own work, but at a guess can you set LLD to 1 on the higher numbered procs, allocate to a size commensurate with that, e.g. Allocate( a( 1:1, 1:0 ) ), and just proceed? LLD after all is just to do with the shape of the arrays you are providing as arguments, and if the other arguments say there is no actual data in those arrays they shouldn't be touched.

Comment: I did something similar now. I padded with 2*NPROCS rows of zeros and copied only the first two rows. Dirty and pointless workaround, but hey, whatever works...